# Android: Find Fragment within a dynamically created Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to get a hold of a fragment that is within a LinearLayout I have created:

**Edit:** This is within a class that extends `ArrayAdapter<G>`

```
LinearLayout newView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
LayoutInflater li;
li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
li.inflate(resource, newView, true);
```

Within the layout is a fragment called TableRowView:

**Edit: I corrected the XML syntax**

```
<fragment android:name ="mypackage.TableRowView"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

How do I get a hold of `newView`'s fragment?

Thanks in advance,
--David

Comment: "Within the layout is a fragment called TableRowView" - that is the syntax for a `View` or `ViewGroup`. Fragments in layouts are via `<fragment>` elements.

Comment: Alright, I'll get that fixed, thanks. I think the question still remains valid.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get a hold of a fragment that is within a LinearLayout I have created

The fragment is not within a `LinearLayout`. A fragment is not a `View` and does not reside inside a `ViewGroup`. The `View` created by the fragment in `onCreateView()` will reside in a `ViewGroup`.

> I am trying to get a hold of a fragment that is within a LinearLayout I have created

Try calling `findFragmentById()` on the `FragmentManager`, provided that you set an ID on `newView` before the inflation operation.

Comment: I'll get the xml layout fixed. I totally left out the piece of the question that is troubling me. I am not calling this within an activity. Rather, I am calling it from a class that extends ArrayAdapter<G>. How can the FragmentManager know which Fragment I am referring to if I have multiple instances of this layout?

Comment: @Davidguygc: I am not certain fragments can go into an `AdapterView`. `ViewPager` and its adapters (e.g., `FragmentPagerAdapter`) do some fairly special stuff for pages-as-fragments, which `AdapterView` does not do. I also do not know what you think you are gaining by using fragments in an `AdapterView`.

Comment: I am trying to create a list of fragments. I'm still really new to Android dev so if that still doesn't make sense to you, please let me know.